# Are bridges a way to prevent identifying Tor exit nodes?

Tags: exit-relays, bridge

I'm using Tor 0.2.8.9 on Mac.  I've come to realize that Tor exit nodes are easily identified, and as such, someone can block access to a Tor browser by simply blocking the IPs correspoding to those exit nodes.  I've read a little bit about bridges and my quesiton is, does using a bridge with Tor prevent people from knowing what exit node you use?

Answer (score 1):

nope, not at all. Using a bridge is a way to *enter* the Tor network, it has literally nothing to do with *exiting* it: you will have the IP address of the exit node used. When any detector like TorDNSEL will probe the exit node - it will flag it(it's outbound IP, in particular) as an exit. Bridges are a great helping hand in entering the network, but it's not related to the exiting mechanism at all. Even if you will use bridges on the exit node - it won't change it's outgoing IP. A thing that can potentially help it is a VPN on an exit node side: of course, it won't change the exit node's id/hash in Tor network, but it can change it's outgoing IP if you will switch your VPN connections to obtain a different outbound IP for an exit node. However - it seems to me that such kind of hiding techniques won't help greatly. The whole architecture of Tor network is to protect *the client*, or *the incoming connection*. Other things like Hidden Services and Exit nodes are much less protected from a tracking techniques.

Comment: How woudl a VPN help?  If I log in to a VPN and launch my Tor browser, the  web site is still going to see the exit node as opposed to the VPN IP, right?

Comment: A VPN on the exit node side, sorry - I was not clear enough in this matter, updating my answer. If on a client side you will launch a VPN - yes, you're 100% correct - it won't change a thing